# ¿Cómo calcular la cabida máxima de una bodega con excel?

Tags: excel, algoritmos, formulas

Estoy tratando de calcular cuántas estanterías o racks caben en un espacio dado, y el espacio va variando en sus dimensiones (distintas bodegas). Me gustaría saber cuántas estanterías caben en cada bodega.

Las estanterías miden 91 cm de largo por 51 cm de ancho, y el espacio mínimo entre ellas debe ser de 70 cm.

Las estanterías se disponen paralelas al eje más largo del recinto, y el cálculo de esa cabida es simple:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(largo_recinto/largo_rack,0)
```

donde "largo_recinto" y "largo_rack" son las celdas que contienen los valores respectivos, redondeados para abajo.

Mi problema es que no logro resolver matemáticamente (o en términos de algoritmo si se quiere) cómo calcular el ancho.

Las condiciones son las siguientes:

Ancho de cada estantería es 51 cm
Espacio mínimo entre estanterías es 70 cm

Entonces si tuviera un espacio de 121 cm de ancho, cabría una estantería y un pasillo, que es el mínimo; luego si tuviera un espacio de 172 cm de ancho la cabida sería de 2 estanterías y así.

¿Cómo formulo el problema para entenderlo y poder hacer mi calculadora de cabida?

He probado

```
=ROUNDDOWN(ancho_recinto/(ancho_estantería+pasillo),0)
```

pero si tengo 172 cm de ancho el resultado es 1, y yo sé que caben 2 estanterías y un pasillo porque 51+70+51=172

Evidentemente estoy planteando mal el problema, me pueden ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando la información proporcionada en la pregunta, la "unidad" es la suma de ancho del estante más el ancho del pasillo y el "complemento" es el ancho del estante.

- Usa la división y redondeo hacia abajo para obtener la cantidad de unidades.
- Usa la función MOD (módulo) para obtener el residuo de tu división y luego verifica si ese espacio es suficiente para tu "complemento".

Dado que cada unidad tiene sólo un estante, no requerimos hacer otra operación.

Asumiendo que la hoja de cálculo tiene la estructura siguiente:

```
     A         B
 1 Estante      51
 2 Pasillo      70
 3 Unidad      121
 4 Bodega      172
 5 Estantes      ?
```

La fórmula en B5 sería

```
=ROUNDDOWN(B4/B3,0)+IF(MOD(B4,B3)>=51,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, deberías utilizar como unidad de medida primaria el ancho de 2 estanterías + pasillo, ya que cada estantería debería necesitar un único pasillo (bastaría con acceder por un lado, como la que están contra la pared):

E | P | E | E | P | E...

Y en el resto comprobar si cabe el ancho de 1 estantería + pasillo o no para completar el almacén.

Comment: Pero para mi calculadora el resultado mínimo razonable es E+P y prefiero que siempre haya un P entre cada E, a menos que el último E esté contra la pared, o dicho de otra manera, que no quepa P+E luego del último E.

Comment: De todas formas gracias por la respuesta y puede ser interesante evaluar la configuración EPEEPE

Comment: Pues entonces la unidad primaria es E+P, y en el resto compruebas si cabe E, ya que la unidad primaria siempre acaba en P (pasillo). Siempre es conveniente rellenar desde una pared. Aunque el espacio es menos efectivo en concepto de almacenaje total.